# Finding Key Symbol name for Windows Button

Tags: xorg

How can I find the Key Symbol name for Windows button of my keyboard?

I know that I can use `xev -event keyboard`, but that's not working for Windows button.

Any ideas/pointer for this ?

This is how I find key symbol for other keys:

```
$> xev -event keyboard                (Then press some button)
KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x1800001,
    root 0x8e, subw 0x0, time 709808, (27,293), root:(28,384),
    state 0x0, keycode 60 (keysym 0x2e, period), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2e) "."
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I find that `period` is the key symbol name for that key. This method doesn't work for window button.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't' work for the super button? What output does xev give when you try?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can occur if the keyboard type is not defined in X so it's worth checking, if you haven't already ;)

Comment: Perhaps you can describe how you can check if its not defined?